# Why does PyCharm show an empty Django Model Dependency Diagram

Tags: django, pycharm, diagram

The PyCharm Pro IDE has a convenient feature called a Django Model Dependency Diagram, which visualizes the relations between your Django models.

However, every so often, this diagram turns up blank, or does not work at all, without any error messages (except in the logs). There's a related issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39831

What could possibly cause the Django Model Dependency Diagram to turn up empty?

There are some causes I know of, although some are difficult to reproduce:

1. no custom apps registered in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
2. path to `settings.py` not properly set in PyCharm's `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Django > Settings`  (this may happen e.g. after using `Refactor > Rename` on the folder containing `settings.py`)
3. in some cases, diagram creation works for independent `models.py` files, but fails if models are imported

Comment: This should be fixed in PyCharm 2021.1. See issue above.